# Keras callback for intermediate dense layer output

Tags: json, python-3.x, callback, keras

I'm trying to implement a callback that at the end of training saves the output of an intermediate dense layer to a json file. My attempt creates the file and doesn't error, but the file is empty. How should I go about this?

```
import json
json_log = open('fingerprints.json', mode='wt', buffering=1)
fingerprint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(
    on_train_end=lambda _: json_log.write(
        json.dumps({'fingerprints': model.layers[-5].output})))
```

Comment: Numeric output of a layer is defined only when you give the model input array(s) and run the computation graph. `.output` attribute only gives you a symbolic tensor which by itself does not contain anything.

Comment: The computation graph isn't being ran when the callback is executed with `model.fit()`?

Comment: Of course no. Think about it this way: when you say "run", it means you give the model some inputs and in return get some outputs. Where do you give the model the required inputs in the callback?

Comment: If you would like to get the output of some layer (given some input, of course) after training, you can define a backend function or another model. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234289/2099607) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019631/2099607) answers as examples of this.

Comment: Thanks. Yep I ended up just defining another model. Have to run the data through another time though.